How to read a dataframe with inferschema as true
I have a dataframe df1 with all the columns are in string(100+ Columns), now i want to cast it to appropriate type with inferschema
Like, for example what we do if we have a csv file and we want the inferschame
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(csvFilePath)
Expecting something like,
val df = df1.read.option("inferSchema", "true")
A new df with appropriate datatype,
Note that we can't change the df1
Need the solution that will work on databricks

can you add sample input output dataframes?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To change the data types of the column as per the column data, you need to check each column data for each data type and cast it as per the data type. This involves lot of manual operations as per the data.
Instead of that, you can directly get the required dataframe by using csv file.
First write the dataframe to a csv file in dbfs like below.
df.write.csv('/Filestore/tables/two.csv',header = 'true')

Then, read the csv file to a dataframe by enabling the inferschema.
df2=spark.read.option('InferSchema','True').csv('/Filestore/tables/two.csv',header = 'true')
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()


